# how to solve certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --dns-azure-config

Tags: azure, dns, ssl-certificate, certbot, certbot-dns-plugin

I want to create SSL certificate using azure dns refering to this tutoriel : https://medium.com/@jibinpb/lets-encrypt-certificate-with-azure-dns-b9ed32ae5aee
The problem that when i run

```
 sudo certbot certonly --dns-azure-config ~/azure_certbot.ini -d "mydomain.com"
```

I got this error :
[image]

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: And did you install the certbot plugin for Azure DNS, as outlined in the tutorial?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes i followed the tutoriel commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error due to certbot not recognizing the --dns-azure-config the DNS plugin for Azure in certbot may not be installed properly.

```
Error:usage: certbot [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ... Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates. By default, it will attempt to use a webserver both for obtaining and installing the certificate. certbot: error: unrecognized arguments: --dns-azure-config /home/xxxx/azure_certbot.ini
```

[image]

To resolve this issue, make use of below command:

Install `sudo apt install certbot` use the manual mode of certbot with DNS challenges to obtain a certificate for your domain with below command.

```
sudo certbot --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly -d Mydomain.com
```

[image]

This certbot will prompt you with instructions to add DNS TXT record like below:

```
Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.Mydomain.com with the following value:

abcdefghijklmXXXXXXXXXX
```

[image]

In your DNS management add `TXT` record with the provided name (`_acme-challenge.MYdomain.com`) and `value`.

Wait for the DNS records to propagate it takes time and press `enter` in certbot terminal to continue after you add the DNS TXT record.

Once verified the record it issues the certificate successfully like below:

```
Waiting for verification... Cleaning up challenges
IMPORTANT NOTES:
Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/cert.xxxxx/fullchain.pem
Your key file has been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/cert.xxxxprivkey.pem Your cert will expire on . To obtain a new or tweaked version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run "certbot renew"
- Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so making regular backups of this folder is ideal
```

[image]